# Why is eclipse showing it is a dead code?

Tags: java

```
class PrimeNo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;// assumed to be any random number
        int i;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            System.out.println("Not a prime number");
        else {
            for (i = 3; i < n; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Not a prime number");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Prime number");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a basic code to find a given number is Prime number or not? I tried this by not using flags. Let we assume "n" to be any number. When I run the code it prints both "Prime" and "Not Prime" in different lines. Also, why is this code a dead code? If we go through logic this code should have runned perfectly. Help me out guys!!!

Comment: ok. it prints both, why shouldn't it? and what do you mean by "dead code"? what do you intend this code to do? start with that.

Comment: What part is marked as dead code? The code analysis **knows** that `n` is 8 and simply doesn't make your assumption of "this is a random number". Therefore it realizes that the condition in the first if can never be true and the body is therefore dead code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, even if you keep the n as variable say for example `int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` i++ will be alerted as dead code, this is because of the break; statement.

Comment: Note that the code as written does *not* print both "Prime" and "Not prime". It (incorrectly) prints Prime because 8%3 == 0, but then stops due to the break statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have written a basic code to find a given number is Prime number or
> not? I tried this by not using flags.

Given below is how you can do it without using a `flag`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;// assumed to be any random number
        int i;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            System.out.println("Not a prime number");
        else {
            for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Not a prime number");
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If n % i == 0 doesn't become true throughout the loop, it means n is prime
            if (i == n) {
                System.out.println("Prime number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Not a prime number
```

Note that I have started the loop from `2` which is also a prime number.

Another important thing to consider is that you do not need to divide and check until `n` (i.e. `i < n`), checking till the square root of `n` is sufficient. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) to learn more about it. Thus, an efficient way of doing it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;// assumed to be any random number
        int i, sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            System.out.println("Not a prime number");
        else {
            for (i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Not a prime number");
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If n % i == 0 doesn't become true throughout the loop, it means n is prime
            if (i > sqrt) {
                System.out.println("Prime number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Not a prime number
```

> Also, why is this code a dead code?

When your loop runs for `i = 3`, it will be terminated by `break;` statement. This, `i++` will never get a chance to run and thus, it is a dead code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` is the culprit, it will break at first iteration, `i` will never get incremented and hence dead code.

Comment: Even if I remove the break , the code checks the every condition form i=3 to i<n (in this case till i=7) and prints all the strings. so gives 5 outputs. how can i overcome it ?

Comment: Its because the logic is incorrect, if you don't want to use the flag, you can test for `n % i == 0 || i==n` for a non prime number, just print and return, if all the iteration passes, it concludes that the number is a prime, so outside the loop, you can simply print that its a prime.

Comment: Correction to my above comment, `n % i == 0 ` should be sufficient for non prime number check.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 'break;' in your code, for loop was running only once. This means the 'i++' part in your for loop was never been called and hence the dead code error.

You might want to write your logic something similar to this:

```
class PrimeNo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 8;// assumed to be any random number
        int i;
        boolean isNumberPrime = true;

        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            isNumberPrime = false;

        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isNumberPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNumberPrime) {
            System.out.println("Number is prime number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number is not prime number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He stated in his question, that he wants to try out without using flag.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed the no flag part. We could implement the code as below with no flags:

```
class PrimeNo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 8; // assumed to be any random number
    int i;

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
      System.out.println("Number is not prime number");

    for (i = 2; n > 1 && i < n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number is not prime number");
        break;
      } else if (i == n - 1) {
        System.out.println("Number is prime number");
      }
    }
  }
}
```